# is-invalid class not working in angular forms

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I learn angular forms, but after apply `is-invalid` class in input tag that time border color does not change to red. Why doesn't it happen?

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Bootcamp Enrollment Form</h1>
    <form #userForm="ngForm">

        <!-- Field 1 -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" 
                required 
                #name="ngModel" 
                [class.is-invalid]="name.invalid"
                class="form-control is-invalid" 
                name="userName" 
                [(ngModel)]="userModel.name"
                    
            >
        </div>
```

`class="form-control is-invalid"`  is-invalid class code mention above

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="userName">User Name</label>
      <input type="text"  name="userName" id="userName" 
          required 
          #userName="ngModel" 
          [class.is-invalid]="userName.invalid"
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="model.name"       
      >
  </div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmj4d9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[ngClass]` in div `form-group` for change border color when invalid event or valid event . like below

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{
'has-error ': nameFormNg.invalid && nameFormNg.touched,
'has-success ': nameFormNg.valid && nameFormNg.touched
}">

<label for="name" class="control-label ">Name :
</label>
<input id="name" required placeholder="" #nameFormNg="ngModel" name="nameForm"
    [(ngModel)]="nameForm" class="form-control" type="text" />
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/border-input-event)